Importing ResNet50 model - size must be positive
I am running this code on tensorflow 2.17.0. I had no problem using this code in the later version tensorflow 2.18.0, but for some compatibility reasons I have to use the older version.
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50

base_model = ResNet50(
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),  # Shape of our images
    include_top=False,  # Leave out the last fully connected layer
    weights='imagenet'
)

I am left with this error:
*ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 3
      1 from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
----> 3 base_model = ResNet50(
      4     input_shape=(224, 224, 3),  # Shape of our images
      5     include_top=False,  # Leave out the last fully connected layer
      6     weights='imagenet'
      7 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/meht/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/applications/resnet.py:409, in ResNet50(include_top, weights, input_tensor, input_shape, pooling, classes, classifier_activation, name)
    406     x = stack_residual_blocks_v1(x, 256, 6, name="conv4")
    407     return stack_residual_blocks_v1(x, 512, 3, name="conv5")
--> 409 return ResNet(
    410     stack_fn,
    411     preact=False,
    412     use_bias=True,
    413     weights_name="resnet50",
    414     name=name,
    415     include_top=include_top,
    416     weights=weights,
    417     input_tensor=input_tensor,
    418     input_shape=input_shape,
    419     pooling=pooling,
    420     classes=classes,
...
File h5py/h5t.pyx:1731, in h5py.h5t.py_create()

File h5py/h5t.pyx:1544, in h5py.h5t._c_string()

ValueError: Size must be positive (size must be positive)

How can I load ResNet50 along with the weights for image feature extraction problem?

Please check your Keras and Keras-Applications versions and try upgrading them with !pip install -U keras keras-applications. I tried with TensorFlow==2.17.0 and it worked without any errors. Please refer to this gist file.
